# how to reverse order of xml using javascript

Tags: javascript, xml

i want to reverse the order of this list using javascript i have tried different ways that i knew about it is 
the below file show straight i want to reverse it.i dont know xml node much and how to get it reverse it totally

```
<messages>
    <messageset>
        <name>torje</name>
        <time>1533904431</time>
        <message>Vvvhjhf</message>
    </messageset>
    <messageset>
        <name>moneyman</name>
        <time>1533904437</time>
        <message>njkjlmkmkl</message>
    </messageset>
    <messageset>
        <name>anjali</name>
        <time>1533904445</time>
        <message>A hi fyi bk MLS egg FG ch bhi CDG jk IC</message>
    </messageset>
</messages>
```

it the present code this shows order wise table like `torje -  Vvvhjhf , moneyman - njkjlmkmkl, anjali - A hi fyi bk MLS egg FG ch bhi CDG jk IC`  this should be reverse first anjali's msg then moneyman then torje's (sorry for bad typing in message)

```
function fetch() {

        setTimeout( function() {
        loadDoc()
        fetch();
    }, 100);

}


function loadDoc() {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      myFunction(this);
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "../clubs/club.xml", true);
  xhttp.send();
}
function myFunction(xml) {
  var i;
  var xmlDoc = xml.responseXML;
  var table="<tr><th>NAME</th><th>message</th></tr>";
  var x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("messageset");
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) { 
    table += "<tr><td>" +
    x[i].getElementsByTagName("name")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
    "</td><td>" +
    x[i].getElementsByTagName("message")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
    "</td></tr>";
  }
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = table;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can create an array and push each data row into the array then `Array#reverse()` that array and convert back to string using `Array#join()`

```js
function myFunction(xml) {
  var rowsArray =[]
  var i;
  var xmlDoc = xml.responseXML;
  var table="<tr><th>NAME</th><th>message</th></tr>";
  var x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("messageset");
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    // new variable `row`
    var row = "<tr><td>" +
    x[i].getElementsByTagName("name")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
    "</td><td>" +
    x[i].getElementsByTagName("message")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
    "</td></tr>";
    // add row to array
    rowsArray.push(row)
  }
  // reverse and return array to string
  table += rowsArray.reverse().join('');
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = table;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Currently your for loop processes the messages in standard order.

`for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {`

You could just reverse this loop:

`for (i = x.length - 1; i >= 0; i—-) {`

Comment: don't know why i didn't think of that simple approach